# SQL, объединение уникальных данных из 1 таблицы во вторую

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

У меня есть 2 одинаковые таблицы ( просто одна до 15.12 числа, другая начинается с 16.12 числа) Во второй БД есть значения до 31.12.2021 и след значение с 16.12. Мне надо взять уникальные значения из первой БД и добавить их во вторую.
Как лучше это сделать?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaSla.png) Это разрыв в первой БД.
А во второй БД всё идет по порядку, но до 16.12

Я пробовал INSERT, но они просто объединяются.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGW3V.png) Я так понимаю нам нужен подобный JOIN. Я новенький в SQL, не судите строго!

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/sl9JxPQ3) простенький пример, похожий на вашу задачу.

```
insert into tableB (dttm,keyval)
select a.dttm,a.keyval 
from  tableA a left join tableB b on b.dttm=a.dttm 
where b.id is null;
```

Делаем соединение двух таблиц по нужной комбинации ключей, исключаем несовпавшие и добавляем результат в таблицу B.  В примере ключем взято "дата-время" - просто так, "за неимением гербовой бумаги, пишем на простой")